# Webmatrix - PHP - Wordpress (not working)

Tags: php, wordpress, webmatrix

I have spent 2 days and have read multiple posts / articles re this subject with no resolution. I am running WebMatrix 2 on XP Pro with sp/3. WM works like a charm until I try to open Word Press through Web Gallery. Every time I get a message that the

"installation failed because php-cgi.exe is not available. Please rerun the Windows installer for PHP and enable either 'IIs FastCGI' or 'Other CGI'."
 The PHP starter site also fails for the same reason.

Apparently all php files were installed by webmatrix (including php-cgi.exe) so I can't figure out why word press (and the PHP starter site) fails and keeps throwing this error.

I even tried a totally new install of WebMatrix on an unused laptop with no existing PHP or mySql files and got exactly the same result. Apparently, there is a flaw built in to the WebMatrix program regarding running PHP.

I have a hard time believing that MSFT would even release this with such a functionality problem. I am not knocking MSFT because I think WM is an awesome product. But, if there are known post installation steps which need to be taken, a heads up would have been nice. I hope WebMatrix 3 users are not encountering the same problem.

Has anyone been able to figure this out?
Any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you watched this video? and followed all the instructions?

[Installing Wordpress on Webmatrix](https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=457944337233)

php-cgi.exe is a file which IIS runs to emulate PHP. This error is todo with the configuration of you IIS server on Windows.

Also have a look at this, which shows you how to install fast cgi on IIS

[Installing Fast CGI with IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/fastcgi-for-iis)